# Why is my training model not predicting correct result?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I have taken a stock price and a day number as the input data.

There are about 1365 input data, but my model is not able to predict the correct value of **`m`** ( slope ) and **`b`** of my regression problem, using a gradient descent optimizer in TensorFlow.

I have also tried to take different values for the learning rate `( 0.0000000001, .., 0.1 )`, but none of them worked.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size=8
ds=pd.read_csv("FB.csv",sep=",",header=None)
x_data=np.array(ds[0].values)
y_true=ds[1].values
x_data=np.array(x_data)
m=tf.Variable(2.2)
b=tf.Variable(0.5)
x_act=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batch_size])
y_act=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batch_size])
y_model=m*x_act + b
error=tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_act-y_model))
optim=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0000001)
train=optim.minimize(error)
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    batches=1700
    for i in range(batches):
        rand_ind = np.random.randint(len(x_data),size=batch_size)
        sess.run(init)
        feed = {x_act:x_data[rand_ind],y_act:y_true[rand_ind]}
        sess.run(train,feed_dict=feed)
    model_m,model_b=sess.run([m,b])
model_m
model_b
y_ans=(model_m*len(x_data)+1) + model_b
y_ans
```

Comment: It is a time dependent data and hence you should try time series algorithms like ARIMA. If you want to do a neural network, you could model an LSTM which is a type of recurrent networks.

Comment: @pissall Thanks for the suggestion. But as I am a beginner in Machine Learning can I know why won't this network work as we are plotting our data in terms of number of days passed and their stock value each day. In this way we can draw a line and going through the middle of the plotted pattern and predict the value corresponding to that line. Its as same as area value problem I think. Whats the difference between two?

Comment: That is linear regression and it won't account for the 'time' element. Time series is something that occurs periodically like the stock market which would go up and down everyday. That's not the same with house prices or something which can be deduced by linear regression. To bring into account the time element of the stocks, you need to model them with it using time series analysis of some kind.

Comment: @pissall Is there any tutorial for the LSTM and ARIMA to refer to?

Comment: Yes. You can look for ARIMA and LSTM tutorial on machinelearningmastery.com, it's a wonderful resource. Read the theory of both the models and refer to the code on that website.

Comment: @pissall with all respect, while Jason is selling "mastery" lectures, any over-simplified approach, demonstrated on "idealised" DataSets, does not create much of the know-how a Trading system practitioner needs for achieving a robust trading augmentation. A blind belief is the worst product one ought expect of such bargaining.

Comment: That's very true. Stocks data is not something we can put through an ARIMA or LSTM. It would take a lot of text mining and what not and still the market would be unpredictable. Jason's approaches in this matter, haven't helped me in real life. And when I've tried to reproduce his results, I've found a lot of errors too. Putting that aside, for a starter it's still cool to understand how it would work.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Having spent more than +20 years in trading, quant-modeling and Machine Learning augmented decision support for FX-trading, there are few things I can help you understand before you start investing your time and efforts in a completely wrong direction. Linear regression model, reported above, has flaws, detailed below, which will **not** be salvaged if moving to any of the few more complex auto-regressive models ( ARMA / ARIMA ) and similarly even the LSTM-tools will **not** save a naive, skipped or underestimated system identification ( as it is common to call it in technical cybernetics ). Simply put, any-Model setups, that try to indoctrinate some Model-behaviour and abstract from non-TA behaviour-mode-switching, are principally blind and singlehanded for handling a complex ( almost hyperchaotic, in extended Lyapunov sense ) multi-agent ecosystem.</sup>

---

### Why my training model not predicting correct result?

Because your assumption is straight wrong.

There are no such stocks, that behave as a linear model, whereas your instructions are strictly opposite,
you ask your linear model **`yPREDICTED = m.X + b`**
to find such **`m`** and **`b`**
so that the overall sum of penalty-errors is minimal.

Having found such **`m`** and **`b`**, for which the sum of penalty-errors is minimal, the learner, that you have pre-selected to use, has finished it's role.

Right, **that means**, you can be mathematically sure, there is no such other `m` and `b`, that would yield lesser sum of penalty-errors, computed as per your selected method, on the available ( and the same used part thereof ) of the observed examples.

---

### While all was done according to an agreed plan,
 that still does *NOT* make The Market 
to start to "*obey*" the `m.X + b` linear behaviour...

If you forget to realise this iron-cast irony, you just started to blindly believe, that linear model rules the real-world ( which we second by second witness it indeed does not ).

So **YGWYT** -- **Y**ou **G**et **W**hat **Y**ou **T**rain

If you train a linear model `m.X + b`, **you cannot be surprised to get nothing else but a least-wrong linear model `m.X + b`.**

---

## Predictions simply have to systematically follow the Model

which means, **all your predictions have to systematically be wrong, just by sticking to the least-wrong linear model `m.X + b`**

Q.E.D.

Comment: Can you help me solve this problem. What am I supposed to do then.

Comment: First, get you legs down, to stand firm on Earth again. **Imagine** that the best **brains** and concentrated immense amount of resources-pools have already spent about 6 decades ( yes, 60+ years ) on advanced solutions, grounded on the best knowledge of cybernetics, optimisation and domain-knowledge ( quant-modelling + trading + behavioural economics ). So, try to resist from ( and do not expect anything extraordinary from ) picking any low-hanging fruits. **Next**, admit one has to learn darn large amount of inter-disciplinary skill to become ready to at least formulate problem to solve.

Comment: Having done so, you only can start to experiment on your own modeling of the reality. If you have Project financing, better hire a professional, than trying to find an easy shortcut, when trying not to spend **man*years** on mastering things, that have been already solved somewhere in the past. No way. Prototyping smart, smarter and the smartest solutions requires above average, best available and the unique white unicorns, so get ready to pay them, or skip this domain and rather start with some under average problem sets. No offense, just can save several decades of wasted time and resources.